# Add MapQuest Map with AS3

Tags: mapquest

I'm trying to add a mapquest map to my flash application, but it only ever publishes a blank swf. I've already imported the latest mapquest SWC file, I have a key, and I'm using the code I found on the mapquest website:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import com.mapquest.tilemap.*;


        //turn scaling off
        this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

        // create a new TileMap object, passing your platform key
        var map:TileMap = new TileMap("MY KEY HERE");

        //set the size of the map
        map.size = new Size(600, 450);

        //add the map to the sprite.
        addChild(map);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [Open Flash Maps API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/flash) with your Free & Open API key?

Comment: No, I'm using an enterprise key. Will the above example only work with the Free & Open API key?

Comment: Ah, it looks like you're using the Flash Maps API with the Flash IDE instead of Flex.  Do you have the following paths in your library: flex_sdk/4.6.0/frameworks/libs/core.swc and the Mapquest API MQFlashMapsAPI_7.1.5_MQ.swc?